# Can't find the list of commits for one developer on a github repo

Tags: list, github, commit

I'm using the code from a github repo for my project, and have been trying to understand some of the dev history about a problem I'm having. However, I'm unable to list the commits from one particular developer. Usually, you will see a link option to list all the commits, on the page of any one commit of any given author. But for this one dev only, that link isn't there. Github docs say this could be due to that author no longer having a github account, but that isn't the case here. Also, I can manually append a `commits?author=username` to the URL, but that doesn't work either. The only way I can see the commits is to load the network graph, scroll the timeline, and mouse-over each commit dot one at a time. It is a difficult way to scan through dozens of commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done locally. Clone the repo and then use [`log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) or [`shortlog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog):

```
git log --author=author@email.com
```

or

```
git shortlog --author=author@email.com
```

`gitk` also supports the `--author` option to filter commits by author.

Comment: Right you are, the command line solves many problems, I'm just not too handy with it.